# How to retrieve client certificate from rest request in Java

Tags: java, http, jersey, ssl-certificate, jetty

I'm using `Jersey` for `REST` server in `Java` and `Jetty` as web server. I have `self signed` certificates. I want to fetch client certificate details from received HTTP Request. How to obtain the information from `HttpServletRequest`?

One method:

```
X509Certificate certs[] = (X509Certificate[])httpRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

Is this right? This results in exception,

```
Error [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate
```

Should I include any additional `JAR`? Or is there any way to obtain client certificate details?

I also came across,

```
httpRequest.getHeader("ssl_client_cert");
```

Both ways not seems to work for me. How to get the details?

Comment: What happens if you don't cast it to an `X509Certificate` array, but leave it as an Object array? Does that Object array contain an `X509Certificate`?

Comment: What you're doing certainly works for Tomcat. Jersey/Jetty may differ. One thing to check is if the certificate class is in the old package (javax.security.cert.X509Certificate). Note the "javax".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure that your ServerConnector that handles SSL/TLS.
Next, that ServerConnector should have a SslConnectionFactory with a configured HttpConfiguration object within it.
That HttpConfiguration object should have the SecureRequestCustomizer added to it.

In embedded-jetty parlance, it looks like this ...

```java
        // SSL Context Factory
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("/path/to/keystore");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("secret");
        sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePath("/path/to/keystore");
        sslContextFactory.setTrustStorePassword("password");


        // SSL HTTP Configuration
        HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration(http_config);
        https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer()); // <-- THIS LINE

        // SSL Connector
        ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString()),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
        sslConnector.setPort(8443);
        server.addConnector(sslConnector);
```

If you are using a `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}` split on standalone Jetty, then you'll want to check that the `jetty-ssl.xml` is present in your configuration ...

```
$ cd /path/to/my-jetty-base
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar --list-config

Java Environment:
-----------------
 java.home = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre (null)
 java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation (null)
 java.vm.version = 25.202-b08 (null)
 java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (null)
 java.vm.info = mixed mode (null)
 java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (null)
 java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_202-b08 (null)
 java.io.tmpdir = /var/folders/w5/mmnzpk0n369dntp4nszlc8h40000gn/T/ (null)
 user.dir = /path/to/my-jetty-base (null)
 user.language = en (null)
 user.country = US (null)

Jetty Environment:
-----------------
 jetty.version = 9.4.15.v20190215
 jetty.tag.version = master
 jetty.home = /path/to/jetty-home
 jetty.base = /path/to/my-jetty-base

...(snip lots of output)...

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-threadpool.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-webapp.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-plus.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-annotations.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-deploy.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-ssl.xml      <-- THIS LINE
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-ssl-context.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-https.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-jaas.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-rewrite.xml
 ${jetty.base}/etc/demo-rewrite-rules.xml
 ${jetty.base}/etc/test-realm.xml
```

Once you have verified this base level configuration you are good to go with even using those attributes.

Next, when you make a request to that secure connector, the various filters and servlets will have access to a number of request attributes that could prove useful to you.

These are the Servlet spec defined attributes that `SecureRequestCustomizer` adds to your incoming HttpServletRequest.

- `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` holds an array of `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` objects.
- `javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite` holds your negotiated cipher suite as a `String` object.
- `javax.servlet.request.key_size` holds your keysize as an `Integer` object.
- `javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id` holds your SSL Session ID as a `String` object.

These are the Jetty custom attributes that `SecureRequestCustomizer` adds to your incoming HttpServletRequests.

- `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.request.ssl_session` holds the active `java.net.ssl.SSLSession` object for this connection.

Since you are seeing a generic `Object[]` from your attempt to use the attribute, perhaps you should debug and see what those objects actually are.

Consider that something outside of Jetty's control might have replaced them, or made them unavailable to Jetty in the Servlet spec form before you attempted to access them.

- A few 3rd party security libraries have been known to alter these attribute in the past.
- Or you are not terminating the TLS/SSL connection at Jetty, such as at a firewall/router/load balancer (haproxy, nginx, apache httpd, or various hardware) (which means Jetty cannot see the certificate).
- You are not using a normal ServerConnector (such as UnixSocketConnector, LocalConnector, or a custom Connector)
- Or you have a 3rd party security layer in your Java implementation.

```java
Object certs[] = httpRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
for(Object cert: certs) {
  System.out.printf("DEBUG: Cert[%s] = %s%n", cert.getClass().getName(), cert);
}
```