# I want to know whether I am sending the certificate in Request or not

Tags: http

How to trace the HTTPs request in java as I want to know whether I am sending the certificate in Request or not

Comment: Hello Ameya. Welcome to the community! It would help if you enclose what did you try and where did it fail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve client certificate from rest request in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907233/how-to-retrieve-client-certificate-from-rest-request-in-java)